# Magento1.9 : How to get currency symbol data in custom module template file

Tags: magento-1.9, currency

I have created a template file in my custom module and I want to load all currency symbol data in my template file similar to `Manage Currency -> Symbol` block.

I tried :

```
$currencysymbol = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('currencysymbol/system_currencysymbol');
$currencysymbol->getCurrencySymbolsData();
```

But getting error `Call to a member function getCurrencySymbolsData() on a non-object`.

How to get all currency symbol in custom template file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the currency symbols from `Mage_CurrencySymbol_Model_System_Currencysymbol` class.

```
$currencySymbol = Mage::getModel('currencysymbol/system_currencysymbol')->getCurrencySymbolsData();
```